# Unable to clone yocto poky repo in ubuntu PC

Tags: git, yocto

I am working on yocto, trying to clone poky in my PC. In one of my ubuntu PC's I was able to clone poky.git.

```
git clone -b dizzy http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky.git
```

But in another ubuntu PC, I was unable to clone, giving Error 407.

```
a@a-VirtualBox:~$ git clone -b dizzy http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky.git
Cloning into 'poky'...
fatal: unable to access 'http://git.yoctoproject.org/git/poky.git/': The requested URL returned error: 407
```

I thought problem with proxy here. but git clone https://github.com/torvalds/linux.git, 
    which is working. Not sure where i am going wrong.
    Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

On the "another ubuntu pc" location you need to authenticate.

`407` means that you received an error while trying to authenticate to the http proxy. See [here](http://www.w3.org/Protocols/rfc2616/rfc2616-sec10.html) for more details.

Probably only for `http` you need to be authorized, for `https` you don't.

Comment: Thanks dan, worked after using below command git config --global http.proxy http://<username>:<passwd>@ip:<port>

Answer (score 0):

This issue occurs if you are behind a proxy wall. You need to setup `gitproxy`. Requirement is `socat`

Create a gitproxy file in your home environment. Include this line after declaring your `PROXY`

```
exec socat STDIO SOCKS4:$PROXY:$1:$2
```

Add this line in your ~/.gitconfig [core] tab:

```
gitproxy = /home/<linux username>/bin/gitproxy
chmod +x ~/.gitproxy
```